# Refining "good" mixing time estimate

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence, markov-chain, diagnostic

Fix a Markov chain $\{ X_{t} \}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ with mixing time $\tau_{\mathrm{mix}}$. Assume that I know some finite bound on the mixing time $\tau_{\mathrm{mix}} < \tau < \infty$, and that I suspect that my bound isn't very tight (e.g. maybe it is off by a factor of 5).

My question is: for fixed $\epsilon > 0$, can I efficiently leverage this upper bound $\tau$ on the mixing time (and possibly some reasonable amount of additional information, such as knowledge of the stationary distribution up to normalizing constant) to obtain a bound such as:

$\mathbb{P}[\tau_{\mathrm{mix}} > \tau']< \epsilon$,

where $\tau'$ is a random number obtained via simulation that should (hopefully) be smaller than $\tau$ and (after a long enough simulation) quite close to $\tau_{\mathrm{mix}}$? For this to be interesting to me, I need some guarantees that a particular simulation gives me  such an estimate for a particular value of $\epsilon$ - it isn't enough to show that an estimate of the mixing time converges to the correct mixing time eventually (I am aware of this sort of result even without an upper bound on $\tau_{\mathrm{mix}}$, e.g. in recent work of Shalizi and McDonald).

Note that without any upper bound on $\tau_{\mathrm{mix}}$, standard examples (such as the `witch's hat') imply that this is essentially impossible. However, any upper bound on $\tau_{\mathrm{mix}}$ effectively rules out these sorts of worst-case situations.

I would also be interested in hearing about related problems (e.g. with spectral gap replacing mixing times), and about solutions at any level of generality (e.g. it is ok if the refinement only works for target distributions with rapidly-decaying tails, or even only for finite state spaces).